# Stack Overflow With JavaScript Filter Function

Tags: javascript, stack-overflow

Hey guys I was trying to mimic an array with an object in JavaScript. I thought it would be easy to mimic the length function with a getter but it looks like my filter function is leading to a stack overflow. For some reason I can't figure out what is going wrong. Can you spot the error?

```js
const o = {
  0: 'hello',
  1: 'there',
  fakeLen: () => {
    return Object.keys(this).length
  },
  get length() {

    const keys = Object.keys(this);
    const filtered = keys.filter(key => typeof this[key] != 'function');
    console.log('filtered array ', filtered);
    return filtered.length;
  }

};

console.log('correct?  ', o.length);
console.log('wrong? ', o.fakeLen());
```

Maybe I am just tired but I don't see how a filter function can lead to a stack overflow!

Comment: The `.filter()` method will itself have to call the getter for `length`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you invoke the `Object.keys()` method on `this`, you're going to get all the properties inside your object, so `keys` will look like:

```
["0", "1", "fakeLen", "length"]
```

Then, when you filter each key, you use bracket notation on each element in the above array. So, you will do the following:

```
typeof this["length"] != 'function'
```

Because `length` is a getter (due to `get`), the `this["length"]` will cause your `length` method to be called again, thus repeating the process until you get a stack overflow.

```js
const o = {
  get length(){
    this["length"];
  }
};

o.length
```

You can either make your `length` property non-enumerable (as shown by Medet Tleukabiluly), so that when you invoke `Object.keys()` on it, it won't appear in your `keys` list, or, you could simply remove `"length"` from your keys before filtering:

```js
const o = {
  0: 'hello',
  1: 'there',
  get length() {
    const keys = Object.keys(this).filter(key => key !== "length");
    const filtered = keys.filter(key => typeof this[key] != 'function');
    return filtered.length;
  }

};

console.log(o.length);
```

Comment: Thanks Nick! That makes sense now. I couldn't figure out what was triggering the length function!

Answer (score 1):

Proper way

```js
const o = {
  fn: function () {},
  0: 'hello',
  1: 'there',
  fakeLen: function() { // NOT ARROW FN
    return Object.keys(this).length
  }
};
// define getter
Object.defineProperty(o, 'length', {
  enumerable: false,
  get: function() {
    const keys = Object.keys(this);
    const filtered = keys.filter((key) => {
      console.log(this[key], typeof this[key])
      return typeof this[key] !== 'function'
    });
    console.log('filtered array ', filtered);
    console.log('filtered.length', filtered.length)
    return filtered.length;
  }
})

console.log('length  ', o.length);
console.log('fakeLen ', o.fakeLen());
```